# While using Md-select ,How to drop down list in protractor?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, protractor

I am trying to select an option from drop down, but unable to find the locator , i have tried many different things, but it didn't help.

```html
<md-select ng-model="card.type" name="type" aria-label="Select card type" ng-change="$ctrl.onCardSelectionChange(card);$ctrl.onChange(true)" cmtr-no-multiple-bahn-cards="" required="" class="ng-pristine ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-cmtr-no-multiple-bahn-cards ng-touched" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" role="listbox" aria-expanded="false" aria-multiselectable="false" id="select_2162" aria-invalid="true" aria-required="true" aria-owns="select_container_2163" style=""><md-select-value class="md-select-value md-select-placeholder" id="select_value_label_2161"><span>Type</span><span class="md-select-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span></md-select-value></md-select>
<div class="md-select-menu-container md-active md-clickable" aria-hidden="false" role="presentation" id="select_container_2163" style="display: block; left: 52px; top: 137px; min-width: 295.797px; font-size: 16px;"><md-select-menu role="presentation" class="_md" style="transform-origin: 147.898px 8px 0px;"><md-content class="_md">
          <!----><md-option ng-repeat="loyaltyCard in ::$ctrl.loyaltyCards" ng-value="::loyaltyCard.value" tabindex="0" class="md-ink-ripple" role="option" aria-selected="false" id="select_option_2166" aria-checked="true" value="blue_biz"><div class="md-text">
            Blue Biz (AF/KL)
          </div></md-option><!----><md-option ng-repeat="loyaltyCard in ::$ctrl.loyaltyCards" ng-value="::loyaltyCard.value" tabindex="0" class="md-ink-ripple" role="option" aria-selected="false" id="select_option_2167" aria-checked="true" value="partner_plus_benefit_lh"><div class="md-text">
            Partner Plus Benefit (LH)
          </div></md-option><!----><md-option ng-repeat="loyaltyCard in ::$ctrl.loyaltyCards" ng-value="::loyaltyCard.value" tabindex="0" class="md-ink-ripple" role="option" aria-selected="false" id="select_option_2168" aria-checked="true" value="onbusiness_ba_aa_ib"><div class="md-text">
            OnBusiness (BA/AA/IB)
          </div></md-option><!----><md-option ng-repeat="loyaltyCard in ::$ctrl.loyaltyCards" ng-value="::loyaltyCard.value" tabindex="0" class="md-ink-ripple" role="option" aria-selected="false" id="select_option_2169" aria-checked="true" value="SK"><div class="md-text">
            SAS Credit (SK)
          </div></md-option><!----><md-option ng-repeat="loyaltyCard in ::$ctrl.loyaltyCards" ng-value="::loyaltyCard.value" tabindex="0" class="md-ink-ripple" role="option" aria-selected="false" id="select_option_2170" aria-checked="true" value="AY"><div class="md-text">
            Finnair Plus (AY)
          </div></md-option><!----><md-option ng-repeat="loyaltyCard in ::$ctrl.loyaltyCards" ng-value="::loyaltyCard.value" tabindex="0" class="md-ink-ripple" role="option" aria-selected="false" id="select_option_2171" aria-checked="true" value="DY"><div class="md-text">
            Norwegian Reward (DY)
          </div></md-option><!----><md-option ng-repeat="loyaltyCard in ::$ctrl.loyaltyCards" ng-value="::loyaltyCard.value" tabindex="0" class="md-ink-ripple" role="option" aria-selected="false" id="select_option_2172" aria-checked="true" value="D8"><div class="md-text">
            Norwegian Reward (D8)
          </div></md-option><!----><md-option ng-repeat="loyaltyCard in ::$ctrl.loyaltyCards" ng-value="::loyaltyCard.value" tabindex="0" class="md-ink-ripple" role="option" aria-selected="false" id="select_option_2173" aria-checked="true" value="EK"><div class="md-text">
            Skywards (EK)
          </div></md-option><!----><md-option ng-repeat="loyaltyCard in ::$ctrl.loyaltyCards" ng-value="::loyaltyCard.value" tabindex="0" class="md-ink-ripple" role="option" aria-selected="false" id="select_option_2174" aria-checked="true" value="TP"><div class="md-text">
            Air Portugal (TAP)
          </div></md-option><!---->
        </md-content></md-select-menu></div>
```

```
element( by.css('.md-select-menu-container md-option[value="blue_biz"]')).click();
```

Comment: "*...i have tried many different things...*". Show them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i am able to click on drop down ))

```
   var dropdown = element(by.model('card.type'));
      var dropdownItems = element.all(by.repeater("loyaltyCard in ::$ctrl.loyaltyCards"));

      dropdown.click().then(() => {
          dropdownItems.get(2).click();
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `by.cssContainingText()` as follows:

```
element(by.css('.md-select-menu-container md-select-menu md-content md-option')).element(by.cssContainingText('.md-text', 'Blue Biz (AF/KL)')).click();
```

This code selects the option with value 'Blue Biz (AF/KL)'

If above code does not work, please try following code:

```
function clickOption(searchText) {
    let wrapper = element(by.css('.md-select-menu-container'));
    let selectMenu = wrapper.element(by.css('md-select-menu'));
    let mdContent = selectMenu.element(by.css('md-content'));
    let options = mdContent.all(by.css('md-option'));
    return options.filter(el => {
      return el.element(by.css('.md-text')).getText().then(text => text.trim() === searchText);
    }).first().click();
  }

// ...
clickOption('Blue Biz (AF/KL)');
```

In this code all selectors are separated and chained. Like this you can determine which selector actually cannot be found. Maybe it's already the first one. Other than that, this function actually returns the matching `md-option` element. Maybe it's not possible to `click()` the underlying `div`.

Comment: its not finding the element , that's so weird ((

Comment: @nikhil I updated my answer. I noticed a few tags were missing in the selector. This selector should work now or I would be confused as well.Other than that, the first selector was wrong in my previous answer. It was `md-select-menu-container` instead of `.md-select-menu-container`, I forgot the `.` for class names.

Comment: i have tried that earlier too ,my friend :) ,now i am scratching my head

Comment: clickOption(searchText: string) ,types not supported in current javascript ,
getting error 
SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
thinking to use xy coordinates to click on element ,which i don't prefer

Comment: Well I adjusted my answer again for javascript :)

Comment: $('.md-select-menu-container md-select-menu md-content md-option').$$('.md-text', '\n' +
           '            Blue Biz (AF/KL)\n' +
           '          ').click();
i was trying something like this ,but now i think might be there is some compatibility issue, not sure  (((

Comment: Please try out the function `clickOption()` in my answer. You should use a single locator chained to another single locator. With this thechnique you would see which locator actually is not found. Maybe it's the first locator which is not found. Then the behavior would make sense.

Answer (score 0):

This will select text "**SAS Credit (SK)**" in drop down , you can replace value as per your **DOM** :

```
element(by.id("select_container_2163")).element(by.css("[value='SK']")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

This drop down have been made using, `divs and spans` , so **select** class will not work in this case.

You will have to store every element present in drop down using list, then you can select it by the required text. Something like :

```
 List<WebElement> allValues =   driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.md-text"));
     for(WebElement values : allValues) {
         if(values.getText().trim().contains("SAS Credit (SK)")) {
             values.click();
         }   
     }
```

Comment: This doesn't looks like a JavaScript + Protractor syntax

Comment: @Andersson : Yes andersson , it is not in JS , though it is in JAVA.

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't work at all, 
 NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By(css selector, md-select-menu-container)

Comment: @nikhil : Hi ! `By(css selector, md-select-menu-container)` is not provided by me. You can try with the css selector which I have provided in my question. That code is in java , I was not very sure about JS. Let me know if that helps.